# 'd' key works everywhere but in the terminal

Tags: kali-linux

Hi I'm currently on a usb-boot of Kali Linux.
Wherever I type the letter 'd', it works fine as you can read here but when I try to type it in any terminal (Xterm, Qterminal) it does not show anything.
I ran xev to see if my inputs were registering and it gave me this result:
[image: part of the xev output for the keypress event with d]

I looked at possible shortcuts with d but found none in the terminal preferences nor in the keyboard settings.
Any other letter on my keyboard works fine.

Thanks in advance for the help ^^

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: Have you created a `~/.inputrc` file and/or modified `/etc/inputrc`? Did you put any readline key bindings in your shell initialization files (such as `bind` commands in your `~/.bashrc`)?

Comment: I do have an inputrc file (globally) where I uncommented the bell-style none for the system beep. My .bashrc does not seem to contain any bind commands. Note: if i were to want to change these files, I'd have to open them in write mode and for that I might need sudo... which contains a 'd'.

Comment: When editing root files? Of course I can edit my own files without sudo and I do, just suggesting the idea that I'll have to work with a terminal not accepting 'd'.

Comment: Can you look at the output of `stty -a` please. In particular the second/third lines (starting `intr`). Any that have `D` rather than (say) `^D`?

Comment: Oh. If you press Ctrl/V before the `d` does that let you type it?

Comment: No, just this one 'eof = ^D'

Comment: Pressing Ctrl/V and then d let's me type it!

Comment: That'll do for now. There's something grabbing `D` as an action. I thought it might be the terminal line discipline but `stty` suggests not. Next place is `readline` but @steeldriver has [already suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654793/d-key-works-everywhere-but-in-the-terminal#comment1231123_654793) that

Comment: As another said, please transcribe your screenshot in to plain text. Edit your question when doing so. Many here will not try to help otherwise, and many more will not find the question because searching for text cannot find graphical images of text.

Comment: You said you uncommented a global `/etc/inputrc` line... What happens if you change it back to it's original commented form? `xev` is seeing (and sending) the 'd' keypress, but something on the receiving end is... doing something else with it. What happens if you use a different shell? A different terminal application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly it got fixed but I was updating my packages and installing new ones and suddenly it worked again. The fix seems to be permanent now (whatever fixed it, I did not touch the inputrc or bashrc files to fix it). Thanks all for the helpful tips! Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Kali Linux does not use `bash` but `zsh`.  The `zsh` shell does not use `~/.inputrc` nor `~/.bashrc`.